# which is the best way to share data between two servers

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, cron

Hi i have mysql databases on two different servers/machines
I need to pull data from server1 and dump in temp table in server 2 on daily basis

Actually the requirement is that when articles on server 1 are ready to be published on store/server2, i want to populate server2/store with that data

Server1 is on lynix and server 2 is on windows dedicated server

So i need to ask which is the best way of accomplish this
PHP page with button, web services, windows service windows scheduled task or any thing else
please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I'm aware I'm missing some things, I'm just trying to be brief.

```
$s1 = mysql_connect("server1");
$s2 = mysql_connect("server2");

$r = mysql_query("select data from table_name where whatever", $s1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($r))
{
    mysql_query("insert into table_name ('$row[0]')", $s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cron job triggered commandline script on the linux server. Which does something like:

mysqldump .... server1 | mysql -h server2 -uuser -ppassword db_name

Means dumping the table to stdout and directly piping the dump to server2. The exact syntax you can find in man pages of mysqldump.

Comment: Thanks for reply but The mysqldump client can be used to dump a database, i need to pull data from some table of database with joins and put that data in temporary table in server 2

Comment: You can specify which tables to dump. So maybe a SQL script on server1 to collect the data in a temporary table could do the job. Afterwards you can transfer the data by dump and insert server2. on